# How can unions store mutliple values in one memory address in C?

Tags: c

The `union` keyword in C confuses me. From what I have read, unions are used to store different types of data at the same memory address. How can one memory address store different amounts of data. For example,

```
union Data {
   int i;
   float f;
   char str[20];
};
```

The memory occupied from this struct is 20 bytes. How can the `int`, `float` and `char` array hold values all at once in the same memory address?

Comment: "All at once" is the wrong idea — a `union` can hold just one value at any given time, but the values can be of different types at different times.  Use `struct` when you need to hold all the values at the same time.

Comment: "union" has te be understood as a mathematical union "∪". When you unite multiple set all starting from a same boundary, you get a set having the size of the biggest one. Unions are actually used to keep the benefit of typing regardless of the context you're currently running in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can unions store mutliple values in one memory address in C?

They cannot and they don't. Only one of the union members is stored at any one time.

Example:

```
union Data d = {.i = 42}; // d contains only i
printf("%d\n", d.i);
d.f = 3.145f;             // d contains only f
printf("%f\n", d.f);
```

Answer (score 1):

The different members of a union all refer to the same memory address,
Now, a variable of a union type can store an integer, a floating-point number, or a string of characters. It means a single variable, i.e., the same memory location, can be used to store multiple types of data.

When a variable is associated with a union, the compiler allocates the memory equals to the size of the largest member which is an array of characters of size 20 here so (20 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

A `union` only stores one thing at any given time - your `union` type can store *either* an `int` *or* a `float` *or* a string.

Enough space is set aside to store the largest member (in this case, the `char` array), subject to any alignment restrictions.  If you do something like

```
union Data x;
x.i = 10;
x.f = 20.0;
strcpy( x.str, "vootie" );
```

then the only thing that's actually stored in `x` is the string `"vootie"` - the value of `i` was overwritten when you wrote to `f`, and the value of `f` was overwritten when you wrote to `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Unions do not store many values at the same location, only one. But in C you can access another union member reading (or writing) the same location. It is called `union punning`

```
union 
{
    unsigned u;
    float f;
    unsigned char uc[sizeof(float)];
}u;


int main(void)
{
    if(sizeof(u.f) == sizeof(u.u))
    {
        u.f = 1.2345f;

        printf("float value %f is representd as: 0x%x or bytes: 0x%02hhx 0x%02hhx 0x%02hhx 0x%02hhx ", 
                u.f, u.u, u.uc[0], u.uc[1], u.uc[2], u.uc[3]);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zqbMvj6cz